# How can I evaluate the bitwise operator in this condition?

Tags: java, if-statement, bitwise-operators

I just practice some basic Java practice problems and this below shows up.

```
if((b2 = false) | (21 % 5)>2) return true;
```

So b2 is assigned with false and  1 > 2 is certainly false, but how do we evaluate "|" ? should it return true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b2 = false` assigns `false` to the variable `b2`, and the expression has the value `false`. `|` on booleans means "or" (without short-circuit), so it evaluates both operands, and the outcome is true if either operand is true.

It is *not* a bitwise operator. If you use `|` on integers, it is a bitwise operator. If you use `|` on booleans, it is a logical operator.

*Edit:*

`||` is a short-circuit operator. If you write `(a() || b())`, and `a()` evaluates to true, then `b()` will not be evaluated, because the result of the *or* must be true. Single `|` does not short-circuit, so both operands are always evaluated.

Comment: You can still think of `|` as a bitwise operator, even for booleans. What does that mean for a boolean? A boolean can be thought of as a one-bit value (the fact that the JVM uses multiple bits for it is just an irrelevant implementation detail done for performance). If it's only operating on one bit, a bitwise operator is the same thing as a logical operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
(b2 = false)
```

(Edited after khelwood's correction) This is also an assignment, not just a logical operation, so be careful for side effects.

And yes, for a boolean, "|" is "or" (and not bitwise), so if the first operator is true, it will always be true.